# every algebraically closed field $E$ of characteristic $0$ contains a real closed subfield $F$ such that $E=F(\sqrt{-1})$

Tags: field-theory

this problem appear in book : Karpilovsky , Unit Groups of Classical Rings.
i don't know how i can solve this.
the only way comes to my mind is : if we can prove $E$ has a proper subfield F such that $[E:F]<\infty$ then we can use theorem Artin-schreier to prove the result.

theorem Artin-scherier : Let $E$ be an algebraically closed field and $R$ a proper subfield of $E$ such that $[E:R]<\infty$ then $R$ is real cloesd and $E = R(\sqrt{-1})$

sorry for bad english!

Comment: Consider a maximal formally real subfield of $E$...

Comment: should i use zorn' lemma to prove this subfield $L$ exist? but then what? we know $\sqrt{-1} \notin L$ but i don't know how this can help.

Comment: Yes, a use of Zorn's lemma is necessary. Using maximality you can show that the field is real closed and also that $E$ is algebraic over $L$.

Comment: This field $L$ is real closed because no proper algebraic extension of $L$ is formally real. Now suppose $E$ isn't algebraic over $L$. Then there is Transcendental element like $t \in E$ such that $L(t) \subseteq E$. but $L(t)$ is formally real and this is contradiction with maximallity of $L$ so $E$ is algebraic over $L$. Now consider $L(\sqrt{-1})$. This field is algebraic closed so we must have $E=L(\sqrt{-1})$. Am i right? sorry for bad english again!!